# Difference between text-transform: none and text-transform: initial

Tags: css

I am just starting to learn how to code and am currently learning through freecodecamp.org, one of their lessons shows this:

| Value | Result |
| --- | --- |
| lowercase | "transform me" |
| uppercase | "TRANSFORM ME" |
| capitalize | "Transform Me" |
| initial | Use the default value |
| inherit | Use the text-transform value from the parent element |
| none | Default: Use the original text |

I would like to know the difference between text-transform: none and text-transform: initial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-transform:none;` will render the text as it is,

`text-transform:initial:` will restore the CSS property to its initial state. you can read more about [initial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use your example from the link using color: none, and compared it to color: initial and I now understand.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same. The `initial` value of `text-transform` is `none`

> Initial:   none <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#text-transform)</sup>